# motion through color pixels to a particular image?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas

I have prepared custom view code is,

```
  if (myBitmap == null) {
        myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(290, 330, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bmpCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
        intArray = new int[myBitmap.getWidth()
                * myBitmap.getHeight()];
        }

               if (bmpCanvas != null) {
                 bmpCanvas.drawText("C", 80,280, mPaintAlphabet);

         bmpCanvas.drawText("C", 80,280, mAlphaInner);
                }
                myBitmap.getPixels(intArray, 0, 290, 0, 0, 290, 330);
                if (myBitmap != null)
        canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

here intArray has total pixels and some pixels has color.i collect the total color pixels in separate array. Please let me know can i give a motion through color pixels to a particular image?

Comment: Concretize your question please. What do you mean to give a motion through color pixels to a particular image?

Comment: i have one image ,i want give motion to image where pixels has a color.

Comment: Do you want to move some part of your image?

Comment: not same image .i want to move another image